# digit character class in regexp doesn't work in MySQL for me

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query

```
SELECT "T2N1M0" REGEXP "^T[:digit:].*";
```

returns single row with `0` for me.

I would expect it return `1`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one level of square brackets `[]`:

```
SELECT "T2N1M0" REGEXP "^T[[:digit:]].*";
```

You should have gotten this error message that hints at the problem:

> Got error 'POSIX named classes are supported only within a class at offset ' from regexp

More one the syntax for regular expressions are given by the manual page [13.5.2 Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).